# config apache2 for phpmyadmin behind HAproxy

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, haproxy, lamp

I'm looking looking for solving my problem, but still I cannot solve it...

I have a firewall (pfsense) in a cloud VM on which I have a reverse proxy (HAproxy) for balancing and offload https on 2 backend servers.
These 2 servers are classic LAMP (Ubuntu Apache2 2.4.53, PHP 7.4, MySQL)
I 'm using phpmyadmin on a different port (let's say 1234), and I'm using the same domain (example.com) on the reverse proxy which balance to lamp1 or lamp2 depend which address :

- example.com:1234/phpmyadmin1 => LAMP1
- example.com:1234/phpmyadmin2 => LAMP2

All of that works nice, but as I'm still learning, I made mistakes that I realized after few months. I could use php-fpm instead php-mod, I would like to use php8.1 and php7.4 and big mistake my Ubuntu version was 21.04 (yes I stupidly mistake with the LTS...)
So for doing all of that, I finally decide to start a fresh install on a new VM : LAMP3

I have my new LAMP3 with phpmyadmin, I followed DigitalOcean tuto for PHP-FPM, tested with simple web page, I can switch to php8.1 or php7.4. Everything sounds good.

Now I would like to integrate the LAMP3 in the reverse proxy in order to redirect example.com:1234/phpmyadmin3 to my phpmyadmin

When I'm on the VPN I can try http://10.0.0.3:1234/phpmyadmin3 and it works.
But when I try from internet with https://example.com:1234/phpmyadmin3 , I have on error 404 Not Found .

This error 404 mean I'm on the server and not on the reverse proxy. so I'm redirected to the right place.

I changed the config for using original alias (/phpmyadmin) and update it on the reverse proxy. Guess what, it's working ! And I'm sure it's LAMP3 because I have php8.1 for phpmyadmin (that I don't on the 2 others LAMP)

I tried with include the default phpmyamin in the virtualhost, but I prefer having all in 1 place so I made a virtualhost phpmyadmin.conf with all info (see below)
I disable phpmyadmin in apache conf (a2disconf phpmyadmin)
I tried a lot of different things into this virtualhost that now I'm getting lost

I reapeat again, but when I change the alias from /phpmyadmin3 to /phpmyadmin everything works as it should.

So why, where how to solve that ?
What's wrong with my alias  ?

**phpmyadmin.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:17380>
        ServerName localhost
        Alias /phpmyadmin3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin
        DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
            Require all denied
        </Directory>
        <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
            Require all denied
        </Directory>
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
           SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        </FilesMatch>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin.access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

VirtualHost *:17380>
    ServerName example.com
    Alias /phpmyadmin3 /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
       SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Versions**

```
Ubuntu 22.04
apache 2.4.53
mysql 5.7.38
php-fpm7.4
php-fpm8.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I kind if solve my problem...

Instead of using the alias /phpmyadmin3 , I tried with alias /pma3 and /test
And it works !

Soooo... I guess it's something with cache on my server ?
Not with my browser as I tried from different PC with different browser in private mode.

Solve I guess